# Chrome highcharts SVG rendering issue

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, svg, highcharts

I just observed an abnormal behavior in chrome: I use [highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/) pie graph and visualize some data. Although each pie slice has different colors, it shows some slices in black. I suspect it is related generated **svg graph**. Please examine the pictures taken from chrome and firefox  *****.
Any help, suggestion, workaround would be appreciated.

[image: Chrome]
<sub>(source: [i.imm.io](http://i.imm.io/v3mk.jpeg))</sub>

[image: Mozilla]
<sub>(source: [i.imm.io](http://i.imm.io/v3mS.png))</sub>

*Using Win 7 64 bit
Chrome version 20.0.1132.47 m
Mozilla version 13.0.1

Comment: Please add an example, e.g on jsfiddle.net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright guys I found the problem which is in my code. But I learnt something: If you assign `color` attribute to an element, Firefox doesn't check if it has **#** symbol in the beginning but Chrome checks. Therefore, `color:343434` fails in Chrome but not in Firefox.